# Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.Default_aspx' to type 'BasePage'

Tags: c#, .net

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BasePage page = (BasePage)this.Page;
```

In my Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.ascx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>
```

It complains about this code:  **BasePage page = (BasePage)this.Page;**

Any ideas on how I can fix this error?

**Edit:**
Basepage definition:

```
 public class BasePage : Page
```

Comment: Can you show the definition for BasePage please?

Comment: Does the code-behind in Default.aspx subclass BasePage? i.e., it should look something like this: `public class Default_aspx : BasePage`.

Comment: It has Usercontrol instead of : BasePage

Answer (score 1):

Does your ASP.Default.aspx.cs inherit from the BasePage?

The page which this control is rendered in must inherit from BasePage class, not Web.Ui.Page class.

Comment: Well, there's your problem! You can't cast to a base class if your page doesn't inherit that class.

Comment: How do I get Default to inherit BasePage. Is that in the Default.aspx or codebehind?

Comment: Code behind. Instead of your Default inheriting from `Web.UI.Page`, have the `BasePage : Web.UI.Page`, and then `class Default : BasePage`

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're saying Leon. Please explain more.